# Getting 'NotFound: 404: Not Found' error while running odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am getting below error continuously while running odoo 8.

```
2016-01-07 07:10:22,200 4198 ERROR None openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 518, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1358, in _dispatch_nodb
func, arguments = self.nodb_routing_map.bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1433, in match
    raise NotFound()
NotFound: 404: Not Found
```

Can anyone tell me whether it is due to cache or any other server issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you deleted any classes and re-add them

I had same error working with Odoo. It was caused by deleting a class in my .py file and Odoo was looking for it. The code was redundant but I had to put it back in to get Odoo to work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error message when I use any undefined field in xml file or if there is any computed field and the method is not declared. If you have anything similar, please check as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add db-filter 8 and remove other databses
start your fresh db then and check.